# How can i return different objects in same method?

Tags: java

```
Need to return differnent objects in same method?is it Possible to return?

   public class Smoketest(){     
    protected Object getLabTopology() {
        if(labTopology == null) {
            return labTopologyAbstarct;
        } else {
            return labTopology; 
        }
    }
}

public test extends Smoketest()
{

getLabTopology();
 }
```

//Need to do the operation directly without casting .is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can as any object's super class is inhernetly `Object` and that's your return type. But what issue you are facing?

Comment: Uh, yeah; whatever return statement it hits first will terminate the function and return the object.  As long as those are both `Objects` you shout be fine.  Not sure why you didn't just run this and asked here?

Comment: Both are different classes , i dont want to do inherit . how can i return ..
i am getting error
((Object) getLabTopology()).releaseEdpt();

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return something from a method, the method signature will include the type of the returned object. This can be any valid Java type.

The common superclass of all objects is the class `Object`. Thats why you can return anything from a method declared with `Object` as its return type. Generally tough, consumers can´t do much if they see an `Object` being returned from a method.

Consider the following example:

```
public Fruit getFruit() {
    return fruit;
}
```

Here, you can return anything that is a fruit. It can be a `Fruit`, or any object that extends it, like an `Apple` or a `Banana`. Consumers will enjoy this return type a lot more, since it is something specific.

Now, you know that you get back a `Fruit` from this method. What you dont know: What *type* of fruit it excactly is. But what you know is that you can do anything with that fruit that can be done with all fruits, for example eat it:

```
public class Fruit {

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Mhh, tasty!")
    }
}
```

If you want to return objects that are not from the same class, try to introduce a common superclass or interface that extract shared data or operations. If you cannot find any, write two seperate methods that each return their independent object.

Also, you can write a wrapper class that encapsulates your returned objects. That class can then hold more than one object.

```
public Result getResult() {
    return new Result(a, b);
}

public class Result {
    private A a;
    private B b;

    // remainder ommitted
}
```

Comment: Nice answer 1+ for the good efforts to explain concepts, concepts that are complex to newbies